# Solving BVP using shooting method and plotting the result

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am not able to obtain any plot with the following code.

```
P = ParametricNDSolve[{(ϵ Cos[x] (κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x]) - 
     Tanh[κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x])] - κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x]) Tanh[κ (1 + ϵ Sin[
            x])]^2 + κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^4 Derivative[1][
       p][x]))/(κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^2) + 
  2/3 (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^3 (p^′′)[x] == 0, p[0] == 0, p[1] == 0}, p, {x, 0, 1}, {ϵ, κ}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {p[0] == 0, p'[0] == 1}}]

Plot[P[0.8, 100][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in specifying derivatives. Further,"ParametricNDSolve" returns a rules, not a function.

Here is the corrected code:

```
sol = p /. 
  ParametricNDSolve[{(ϵ Cos[
          x] (κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x]) - 
           Tanh[κ (1 + ϵ Sin[
                 x])] - κ (1 + ϵ Sin[
                x]) Tanh[κ (1 + ϵ Sin[
                   x])]^2 + κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^4 p' [
             x]))/(κ (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^2) + 
      2/3 (1 + ϵ Sin[x])^3 p''[x] == 0, p[0] == 0, 
    p[1] == 0}, p, {x, 0, 1}, {ϵ, κ}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {p[0] == 0, p'[0] == 1}}]

Plot[sol[0.8, 100][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"ShootingMethod" isn't necessary, try

```
P = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(\[Epsilon] Cos[
         x] (\[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[x]) - 
          Tanh[\[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[
                x])] - \[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[
               x]) Tanh[\[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[
                  x])]^2 + \[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[x])^4 p'[
            x]))/(\[Kappa] (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[x])^2) + 
     2/3 (1 + \[Epsilon] Sin[x])^3 p''[x] == 0, p[0] == 0, p[1] == 0},
   p, {x, 0, 1}, {\[Epsilon], \[Kappa]}]
Plot[P[0.8, 100][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]